# gcloud build submit failing due to missing permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to upload a docker image build on a VM, but when executing the command:

`gcloud builds submit --tag eu.gcr.io/luccid-mvp/luccid_mvp_app:0.0.1 --verbosity debug`

I receive:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag eu.gcr.io/luccid-mvp/luccid_mvp_app:0.0.1 --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.builds.submit] with arguments: [--tag: "eu.gcr.io/luccid-mvp/luccid_mvp_app:0.0.1", --verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true
DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): metadata.google.internal:80
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true HTTP/1.1" 200 197
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/token
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/token HTTP/1.1" 200 868
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true
DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): metadata.google.internal:80
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true HTTP/1.1" 200 197
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/token
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/token HTTP/1.1" 200 868
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /storage/v1/b/luccid-mvp_cloudbuild?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 404 247
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storage.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "POST /storage/v1/b?alt=json&project=luccid-mvp HTTP/1.1" 403 204
DEBUG: (gcloud.builds.submit) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [luccid-mvp_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission. Giving the user Owner, Editor, or Viewer roles may also fix this issue. Alternatively, use the --no-source option and access your source code via a different method.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 385, in CreateBucketIfNotExists
    self.client.buckets.Get(self.messages.StorageBucketsGetRequest(
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/generated_clients/apis/storage/v1/storage_v1_client.py", line 265, in Get
    return self._RunMethod(
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 743, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 609, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing <https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/luccid-mvp_cloudbuild?alt=json>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ADPycdt-BQs9J9DAHGi1qmVafWijPiwTiVUi8Fgv19rVqzirU84bp8gxJcXYerjzgDlXNFnKZclrA7fD2aYCxDIyI7Tyj5TvJjoQ', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 02 Jun 2023 16:43:59 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'expires': 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-length': '247', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': 404}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "The specified bucket does not exist.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The specified bucket does not exist.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/builds/submit_util.py", line 337, in SetSource
    gcs_client.CreateBucketIfNotExists(
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 402, in CreateBucketIfNotExists
    self.client.buckets.Insert(storage_buckets_insert_request)
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/generated_clients/apis/storage/v1/storage_v1_client.py", line 317, in Insert
    return self._RunMethod(
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 743, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 609, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?alt=json&project=luccid-mvp>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ADPycdsZh9Ln6GomokSkaQQAUuXUiyViOsa1_UIVpudUC6-n1Io5BJwHXnLwU6OiCoYt5Enn-fBGMrdIclXD3kfn4fYbvTSjhcKV', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 02 Jun 2023 16:43:59 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'expires': 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-length': '204', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': 403}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access denied.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access denied.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/builds/submit.py", line 203, in Run
    build_config = submit_util.SetSource(
  File "/home/pascal_gula_luccid_ai/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/builds/submit_util.py", line 348, in SetSource
    raise BucketForbiddenError(
googlecloudsdk.command_lib.builds.submit_util.BucketForbiddenError: The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [luccid-mvp_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission. Giving the user Owner, Editor, or Viewer roles may also fix this issue. Alternatively, use the --no-source option and access your source code via a different method.
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [luccid-mvp_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission. Giving the user Owner, Editor, or Viewer roles may also fix this issue. Alternatively, use the --no-source option and access your source code via a different method.
make: *** [Makefile:39: run_gcr_build] Error 1
```

I added the Service Usage xxx role to the associated 988260741259-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com SA. I also tried to add the Owner role w/o success...

Not sure how long does it take when adding role, but 30 minutes are not enough.

I also added Owner to the 2 SAs associated to Cloud Build w/o any success.

Comment: There are several possibilities. Your post does not have enough details to know for sure. 1) the bucket does not exist. Use the `gsutil` CLI and confirm correct spelling and access. 2) You have not enabled required APIs such as `cloudresourcemanager`. Use the command `gcloud services list --enabled` to list enabled APIs. 3) You do not have permission to the bucket. 4) The bucket is in a different project. 5) the service is using a different service account than you think it is.

Comment: 6) I configure the `gcloud` CLI temporarily with the same service account to make sure the service account has all required permissions and APIs enabled.

Comment: Are you sure you have given the expected permissions to the default SA for Cloud Build : `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` ?

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your useful comment, I finally switch to Artifact Registry since CR is about to phase out and there were no issue on that side!

Answer (score 1):

Since Container Registry is about to phase out, I decided to move to Artifact Registry which was done w/o issue with an example as the following:

```
LOCATION=europe-west3
PROJECT_ID := $(shell gcloud config get-value project)
REPOSITORY=gcf-artifacts
IMAGE_NAME=${APP_NAME}
GAR_TAG := ${LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY}/${IMAGE_NAME}

run_gar_push:
    echo "${GCR_TAG}"
    gcloud auth configure-docker ${LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev
    docker tag ${IMAGE_NAME} ${GAR_TAG}:${VERSION}
    docker push ${GAR_TAG}:${VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things,

1. `gcloud auth list`
   It should show account which got required access.
2. `gcloud config list`
   Check the project and perimeter details
3. Check bucket access by running
   `gsutil ls gs://<bucket name>`
4. If you are running gcloud commands from gcp vm and no account is activated on the cli then it uses service account attached to gcp vm, so make sure to grant required permissions to that account.
5. If the project is protected by vpc sc perimeter then update the perimeter by editing ingress rules to allow cloudbuild account.

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your useful answer! I finally switch to Artifact Registry since CR is about to phase out and there were no issue on that side!